# convert mysql query to eloquent query issue

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have build below query in mysql. and trying a lot to convert to laravel but not success.

```
SELECT u.id, u.purchase_item_name,u.sales_item_name, us.type,
GROUP_CONCAT(p.itemcode) AS purchase_items,
GROUP_CONCAT(s.itemcode) as sales_items 
FROM composite_inventories as u 
LEFT JOIN composite_has_inventories as us ON u.id = us.composite_inventory_id 
LEFT JOIN inventories as s ON US.inventory_id = s.id AND us.type='sale'
LEFT JOIN inventories as p ON US.inventory_id = p.id AND us.type='purchase'
GROUP BY u.id
```

I am trying to above query in to laravel datatabel query but it gives errors as below.

**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'saas.composite_inventories.purchase_item_name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select GROUP_CONCAT(p.itemcode) as purchase_items, GROUP_CONCAT(s.itemcode) as sales_items, `composite_inventories`.`id`, `composite_inventories`.`purchase_item_name`, `composite_inventories`.`sales_item_name`, `us`.`type` from `composite_inventories` left join `composite_has_inventories` as `us` on `composite_inventories`.`id` = `us`.`composite_inventory_id` left join `inventories` as `s` on `US`.`inventory_id` = `s`.`id` and `us`.`type` = 'sale' left join `inventories` as `p` on `US`.`inventory_id` = `p`.`id` and `us`.`type` = 'purchase' group by `composite_inventories`.`id`)**

I have tried below laravel query.

```
$result = Compositeinventory::select([
            DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(p.itemcode) as purchase_items'),
            DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(s.itemcode) as sales_items'),
            'composite_inventories.id',
            'composite_inventories.purchase_item_name',
            'composite_inventories.sales_item_name',
            'us.type'
        ])->leftJoin('composite_has_inventories as us', 'composite_inventories.id', '=', 'us.composite_inventory_id')
            ->leftJoin('inventories as s', function($join)
                 {
                    $join->on('US.inventory_id', '=', 's.id');
                    $join->on('us.type','=',DB::raw("'sale'"));
                 })
            ->leftJoin('inventories as p', function($join)
                 {
                    $join->on('US.inventory_id', '=', 'p.id');
                    $join->on('us.type','=',DB::raw("'purchase'"));
                 })
        ->groupBy('composite_inventories.id')->get();
```

I just tried below query

```
$row = DB::table('composite_inventories as u')->select([
            'u.id',
            'u.purchase_item_name',
            'u.sales_item_name',
            DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(p.itemcode) as purchase_items'),
            DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(s.itemcode) as sales_items')
        ])->leftJoin('composite_has_inventories as us', 'u.id', '=', 'us.composite_inventory_id')
            ->leftJoin('inventories as s', function($join)
                 {
                    $join->on('US.inventory_id', '=', 's.id');
                    $join->on('us.type','=',DB::raw("'sale'"));
                 })
            ->leftJoin('inventories as p', function($join)
                 {
                    $join->on('US.inventory_id', '=', 'p.id');
                    $join->on('us.type','=',DB::raw("'purchase'"));
                 })
        ->groupBy('u.id', 'u.purchase_item_name','u.sales_item_name');
```

above query works when display data table. but when i try to search filter it gives below error because of purchase_items and sales_items field are not present in database but that are just aliases. error is

> Exception Message:↵↵SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1583 Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'LOWER' (SQL: select count  as aggregate from (select `u`.`id`, `u`.`purchase_item_name`, `u`.`sales_item_name`, GROUP_CONCAT(p.itemcode) as purchase_items, GROUP_CONCAT(s.itemcode) as sales_items from `composite_inventories` as `u` left join `composite_has_inventories` as `us` on `u`.`id` = `us`.`composite_inventory_id` left join `inventories` as `s` on `US`.`inventory_id` = `s`.`id` and `us`.`type` = 'sale' left join `inventories` as `p` on `US`.`inventory_id` = `p`.`id` and `us`.`type` = 'purchase' where (LOWER(`composite_inventories` as `u.purchase_item_name`) LIKE %a% or LOWER(`composite_inventories` as `u.purchase_items`) LIKE %a% or LOWER(`composite_inventories` as `u.sales_item_name`) LIKE %a% or LOWER(`composite_inventories` as `u.sales_items`) LIKE %a%) group by `u`.`id`, `u`.`purchase_item_name`, `u`.`sales_item_name`) count_row_table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a laravel's issue your query is invalid because its contains some columns which are not aggregated and not mentioned in group clause. To correct this you need to update your group by clause as

```
group by u.id, u.purchase_item_name,u.sales_item_name, us.type
```

In query builder

```
->groupBy('composite_inventories.id', 'composite_inventories.purchase_item_name','composite_inventories.sales_item_name', 'composite_has_inventories.type')
```

If there are multiple `type`(s) per composite_inventories then i guess you need GROUP_CONCAT for this also and remove this column from group by clause.

Update for syntax error, you are not using [lower](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function correctly just pass your column name for which you want to convert the value to lower case like

```
WHERE (
      LOWER(u.purchase_item_name) LIKE '% a %'
      OR LOWER(u.purchase_items) LIKE '% a %'
      OR LOWER(u.sales_item_name`) LIKE '% a %' 
      OR LOWER(u.sales_items) LIKE '% a %'
)
```

If your database collations are not set to case sensitive then there is no need to use [lower()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) function for more information have a look at [B.5.4.1 Case Sensitivity in String Searches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html)

Also if you are using mysql fucntions in query you might need to `raw()` method of laravel's query builder

Comment: when display databse it works but if i try to search filter it gives error : "Exception Message:↵↵SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1583 Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'LOWER' (SQL: select count  as aggregate from (select `u`.`id`, `u`.`purchase_item_name`, `u`.`sales_item_name`, GROUP_CONCAT(p.itemcode) as purchase_items, GROUP_CONCAT(s.itemcode) as sales_items from `composite_inventories`.........

Comment: @CodeEmbassy update your question and add complete query which produces above error

Comment: i have updated question with complete detail with error.

Comment: hello i have check your updated answer but that will not work. it is not issue of lower function. lower function is by default generated when laravel fires query. issue is because purchase_iteams and sales_items ares aliases and we are using datatable search on that thats why it gives error.

Comment: we need to use having caluse in filterColumn but i have tried but it is not working. may be i do not know exactly how ti put two fields in one having caluse.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, may I ask you to have a look at a yajra dataTable related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208578/laravel-yajra-datatable-cannot-retrieve-the-search-parameter-from-ajax-call-in ?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same problem and after a lot of digging, there must be some conflict with the datatable component of yajra, the solution is to convert the query from eloquent to query builder and problem solved.